# Get contents of a Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating an application and I want to use the entered values in the GUI Entry widget.

How do I get the entered input from a Tkinter Entry widget?

```
root = Tk()
...
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter: get Entry content with get()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/tkinter-get-entry-content-with-get)

Comment: @Rinzler ? This question is older then that one. And why mark as a duplicate right now?

Comment: @Zizouz212 The age of questions [does not matter, per official policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) when closing duplicates. That said, this is not a duplicate, although the two questions have an important relationship. This one is a how-to about getting the information generally; the other is a debugging question about timing and managing events (i.e., *when* to get the information).

Answer (score 30):

You need to do two things: keep a reference to the widget, and then use the [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) method to get the string.

Here's an example:

```
self.entry = Entry(...)
...
print("the text is", self.entry.get())
```

Answer (score 8):

First declare a variable of required type. For example an integer:

> var = IntVar()

Then:

> entry = Entry(root, **textvariable=var**)
>
> entry.pack()
>
> **user_input = var.get()**
>
> root.mainloop()

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this add anything to the current answers @aleksandarkrumov