# Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to use an `Entry` field to get manual input, and then work with that data.

All sources I've found claim I should use the `get()` function, but I haven't found a simple working mini example yet, and I can't get it to work.

I hope someone can tel me what I'm doing wrong. Here's a mini file:

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

Label(master, text="Input: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

content = entry.get()
print(content)  # does not work

mainloop()
```

This gives me an `Entry` field I can type in, but I can't do anything with the data once it's typed in.

I suspect my code doesn't work because initially, `entry` is empty. But then how do I access input data once it has been typed in?

Comment: In your example, what exactly are you expecting? You haven't given the entry widget any text before you call `get` so of course it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It looks like you may be confused as to when commands are run. In your example, you are calling the `get` method before the GUI has a chance to be displayed on the screen (which happens after you call `mainloop`.

Try adding a button that calls the `get` method. This is much easier if you write your application as a class. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        print(self.entry.get())

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Run the program, type into the entry widget, then click on the button.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not really firm on classes yet (still very much a beginner at programming in general), but I see the problem. 
I'll just make an "Analyze!" button and put the get()-function in there, that should work. 
Thank you!

Comment: You might need to add self as a parameter while calling the superclass init: tk.Tk.__init__(self). Otherwise, very useful example!

Comment: And, er, you misspelt app in the last line. <_<"

Answer (score 10):

You could also use a `StringVar` variable, even if it's not strictly necessary:

```
v = StringVar()

e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

v.set("a default value")
s = v.get()
```

For more information, see [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) on [*effbot.org*](http://effbot.org/).

Comment: A `StringVar` isn't necessary, strictly speaking. They are handy, but for this question they are completely superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example without classes:

```
from tkinter import *    
master = Tk()

# Create this method before you create the entry
def return_entry(en):
    """Gets and prints the content of the entry"""
    content = entry.get()
    print(content)  

Label(master, text="Input: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Connect the entry with the return button
entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry) 

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

*

```
master = Tk()
entryb1 = StringVar

Label(master, text="Input: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

Entry(master, textvariable=entryb1).grid(row=1, column=1)

b1 = Button(master, text="continue", command=print_content)
b1.grid(row=2, column=1)

def print_content():
    global entryb1
    content = entryb1.get()
    print(content)

master.mainloop()
```

What you did wrong was not put it inside a Define function then you hadn't used the `.get` function with the textvariable you had set.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put a textvariable in it, so you can use `set()` and `get()` method :

```
var=StringVar()
x= Entry (root,textvariable=var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers I found only showed how to do it with tkinter as tk. This was a problem for me as my program was 300 lines long with tons of other labels and buttons, and I would have had to change a lot of it.

Here's a way to do it without importing `tkinter as tk` or using StringVars. I modified the original mini program by:

- making it a class
- adding a button and an extra method.

This program opens up a tkinter window with an entry box and an **"Enter"** button. Clicking the Enter button prints whatever is in the entry box.

```py
from tkinter import *

class mini():

    def __init__(self):
    
        master = Tk()

        Label(master, text="Input: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        Button(master, text='Enter', command=self.get_content).grid(row=1)
        self.entry = Entry(master)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        master.mainloop()

    def get_content(self):
        content = self.entry.get()
        print(content)  


m = mini()
```