# How to save file with file name used from user's input

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make GUI and would like to have an option to save text file created in this GUI with filename taken from user's input.

Have something like this:

```
script_name_input_area = Entry(
    width = 30).place(x = 100, y = 60)
```

Saving function defined like this:

```
def savef():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/', title="select file", initialfile= ('FIX THIS!!')...
```

Is there a way to incorporate user's ENTRY into initialfile?

Comment: Add an appropriate tag for the GUI library you use (probably tkinter).

Comment: There are countless ways of doing it but all of them are related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28947795/13629335)

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] to show your application design.

Comment: @Thingamabobs. OP wanted how to write to file not how to get user input.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example of how to do this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def savef():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/', title="select file", initialfile= script_name_input_area.get())

root = tk.Tk()
script_name_input_area = tk.Entry(root,width=30)
script_name_input_area.pack()
save_button = tk.Button(root,text="Save",command=savef)
save_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I suspect your issue may have been to do with doing this

```
script_name_input_area = Entry(width = 30).place(x = 100, y = 60)
```

Where you are trying to both create and place the entry widget on the same line. Entry will return a tk.Entry instance but place returns None so script_name_input_area will be equal to None too. Where you need to use a tk widget later, ALWAYS create and pack/grid/place it on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that do what you want, as @scotty3785 said, your issue is because you .place() doesn't return an instance of Entry. You need to create the instance of Entry and after place it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class mainWindow(tk.Tk) : 
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = None #if you need to keep the output filename

        self.script_name_input_area = tk.Entry(self,width=30) #your entry
        self.script_name_input_area.pack() #need to place it AFTER creating it

        saveFile = tk.Button(self,text="Save",command=self.saveFile) #button to save that calls saveFile when clicked
        saveFile.pack() #place button

    def saveFile(self):
        if(self.script_name_input_area.get() != "") : #if your entry is not empty
            with open(self.script_name_input_area.get() + ".txt", "w") as file : #open/create a file called (Entry).txt in write mode
                file.write("") #write what ever you want
        else : #else
            print("please provide something in textField") #please provide something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = mainWindow() #create instance of MainWindow
    win.mainloop() #create a loop of mainWindow until user close the window
```

Hope this will help you ! Keep us updated