# Python Tkinter Error

Tags: python, user-interface, syntax, tkinter, portable-python

I have tried to work with the Tkinter library, however, I keep getting this message, and I don't know how to solve it.. I looked over the net but found nothing to this specific error - I call the library like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

and I get this error -

```
    TclError = Tkinter.TclError
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TclError'
```

I have no clue what can I do now.. 
Thank you

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Shoham/Desktop/MathSolvingProject/Solver.py", line 3, in <module>
from Tkinter import *
File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-    tk\Tkinter.py", line 41, in <module>
TclError = Tkinter.TclError
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TclError'
```

Comment: Are you using PortablePython?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    Yes I do

Comment: add a link to what is in `"C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-    tk\Tkinter.py`, it looks wrong to me

Comment: @PadraicCunningham      What do you mean " Add a link" ?

Comment: Copy the content of the file to pastebin

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    this is the link =    http://pastebin.com/7dzNY2U1

Comment: Try using this file http://pastebin.com/dFiCXv4W, make a copy of the original and replace with that

Comment: You also are using portablepython to run the code yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham     I did that, but now I got another traceback - (look up I changed the error given in the question)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    In pyCharm , I click "run" and select the wanted file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    So what can I do? Is there no way now I can create GUI?

Comment: What caused the new error, just importing or a line later in your code? Does adding `Tk()` after your from `Tkinter import *`  fix the new error?

Comment: I don't know what caused it. I just copied from the link you sent me, and then the traceback  has changed. The code is still the same.

Comment: What happens if you simple run `from Tkinter import *` using the file I provided in place of the original?  Also as previously asked does adding `Tk()` right after the import fix the new error?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham      There is no error.

Comment: And using the original file just importing caused an error yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    Yes

Comment: does adding `from Tkinter import *;Tk()` fix the new error? Add a link to your actual code also

Comment: I reverted your edit as it is what the real issue is, the problem is with portable python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham     http://pastebin.com/n2knv4jS     this is the whole code. Now I have another problem instead - I changed it up in the traceback in the question above.

Comment: Add any errors to pastebin, leave the question as it was because these errors are from something unrelated, the fix has worked, the error is not related to your original question

Comment: Your problem is you are passing an empty string so an empty string cannot be cast to a float

Comment: This question is related to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/tkinter-entry-get-function-is-returning-nothing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham     Why an empty string? I get data from the entry.

Answer (score 2):

You imported (mostly) everything from the module with `from Tkinter import *`. That means that (mostly) everything in that module is now included in the global namespace, and you no longer have to include the module name when you refer to things from it. Thus, refer to `Tkinter`'s `TclError` object as simply `TclError` instead of `Tkinter.TclError`.

Comment: I know that, however, I do not mention it even once in my code.. I just created some GUI's and I get this error

Comment: Maybe you should include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: I did. you can tae a look

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in `"C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py`:

The regular python install imports in `lib-tk\Tkinter.py` are different to what is in `PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py`:

```
try:
    import _tkinter
except ImportError, msg:
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
tkinter = _tkinter # b/w compat for export
TclError = _tkinter.TclError
```

Then where Tkinter is used in PortablePython `_tkinter` is used  instead. It seems like a bug in `PortablePython`.

The full contents of the  file are [here](http://pastebin.com/xAnJhzuB). Replacing the file in `C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py` as per the comments fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like @ErezProductions said. You either have to import everything and access it directly or import only the module.

```
from Tkinter import *
TclError
```

or

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.TclError
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the traceback I gave in the question(look again I added more details)

Answer (score 0):

See the difference:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> TclError = tkinter.TclError
>>>
```

No error. But, with your method:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> TclError = tkinter.TclError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

The difference is that the first method imports the module `tkinter` into the name space. You can address its properties using the dot notation `tinter.property`. However, the `from tkinter import *` imports the module's *properties* into the name space, not the module itself.

Either try the first method given above, or adjust your approach (NB: [importing all properties is a bad idea](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/why-import-star-is-a-bad-idea/)) like so:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> my_TclError = TclError   # renamed because TclError defined in tkinter
>>>
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the traceback I gave in the question(look again I added more details)