# Tkinter Entry widget stays empty in larger programs (Python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to make a program where, after clicking on a button, a user gets asked for its name, after which the program continues. I'm stuck on making the popup return the textstring that has been entered in the popup. At first I thought it was my code, but the I decided to make a second program where it just asks the name, prints it, prints it length and its type. In that second program, everything works as it should. I'm having a very hard time figuring out why it doesn't in the first (larger) program. I've already read ([Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131)) and, even though my `.get()` function occurs after my `.mainloop`, it still doesn't work; in that same thread they propose using classes, which is something I know absolutely nothing about. If possible can anyone point out what I'm missing in my larger program?

---

**Large Program**

---

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Ask-name-SUB")

def getname(usertype):
    getname = Tk()
    getname.title("Get name popup")
    def abort():
        getname.destroy()
    name = StringVar()
    c = LabelFrame(getname, text = "Your name:")
    c.pack()
    d = Entry(getname, textvariable=name)
    d.pack(side="right")
    d.bind("<Return>", lambda event: getname.destroy())
    e = Button(getname, text = "Cancel", command=lambda: abort())
    e.pack()

    getname.mainloop()
    name = (name.get())
    print "Print name, its length, its type"
    print name
    print len(name)
    print type(name)

top = Frame(root)
top.pack(side="top")
bottom = Frame(root)
bottom.pack(side="bottom")
def killit():
    root.destroy()

cancel = Button (bottom, text = "Cancel", command=lambda: killit())
cancel.pack()
askname = Button (top, text = "Enter your name", command=lambda: getname("testuser"))
askname.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

**Small Program**

---

```
    from Tkinter import *

def getname(usertype):
    getname = Tk()
    getname.title("Get name popup")
    def abort():
        getname.destroy()
    name = StringVar()
    c = LabelFrame(getname, text = "Your name:")
    c.pack()
    d = Entry(getname, textvariable=name)
    d.pack(side="right")
    d.bind("<Return>", lambda event: getname.destroy())
    e = Button(getname, text = "Cancel", command=lambda: abort())
    e.pack()

    getname.mainloop()
    name = (name.get())
    print "Print name, its length, its type"
    print name
    print len(name)
    print type(name)


getname("testuser")
```

Comment: larger program doesn't work for me because you mess with name `getname` - you define function `getname` and you use it in widgets because you think you have `getname = Tk()` but it is not true.

Comment: BTW: we use `Tk()` to create only main window. If you need popup/dialog window then use `Toplevel()`

Comment: BTW: probably your large program has wrong indentions - but I think problem is because program should have only one `mainloop()` (and only one `Tk()` as main window)

Comment: Thanks so much Furas,

I'll try this in the morning. Can I just ask two small other questions, do I just use 'popupname = Toplevel()' or do I use 'popupname = tk.Toplevel()'. And do I leave the 'mainloop()' out in its entirety, or do I need to replace that by something specific to the 'Toplevel()' (I can't find this in the Tkinter documentation). 

Sorry about the indentation. When pasting my code in stackoverflow I lost all indents and forgot to fix that. - I'll edit it right away.

Comment: if you already use `from Tkinter import *` then you have to use `Toplevel()` without `tk.` But if you use only `import Tkinter as tk` then you will have to use `tk.Toplevel()` but also `tk.Tk()` and `tk.Label()`, `tk.Button()`, etc. It need more changes in code but it can be more readable because you can use normal `tk.Button()` and themed version `ttk.Button()` and own class `Button()`.

Comment: keep `root.mainloop()` in current place - don't use it in inside functions ie. `popupname.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your large program - probably you have wrong indentions.

I see two problems:

- program should have only one `mainloop()` - and it can be your problem.
- we use `Tk()` to create main window, and `Toplevel()` to create other windows.

Besides you use name `getname` as function name and as second window instance so it is very misleading.

I create global `var_name` to keep name and later I use it inside function.

```
from Tkinter import *

def get_name(usertype):

    win = Toplevel()
    win.title("Get name popup")

    f = LabelFrame(win, text = "Your name:")
    f.pack()

    # use global `name` which was created outside function
    e = Entry(win, textvariable=var_name)
    e.pack(side="right")
    e.bind("<Return>", lambda event: win.destroy())

    b = Button(win, text = "Cancel", command=win.destroy)
    b.pack()

# --- main --

root = Tk()
root.title("Ask-name-SUB")

# global variable
var_name = StringVar()

b = Button(root, text="Enter your name", command=lambda: get_name("testuser"))
b.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Cancel", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()

# --- after --
name = var_name.get()
print "Print name, its length, its type"
print name, len(name), type(name)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To makes popup window more universal you can use arguments - displayed text and variable for result.

```
def get_value(text, variable):
```

and then you can use it with different text and different variable - ie. for name or for address.

```
from Tkinter import *

def get_value(text, variable):

    win = Toplevel()
    win.title("Get value")

    f = LabelFrame(win, text=text)
    f.pack()

    e = Entry(win, textvariable=variable)
    e.pack(side="right")
    e.bind("<Return>", lambda event: win.destroy())

    b = Button(win, text = "Cancel", command=win.destroy)
    b.pack()

# --- main --

root = Tk()
root.title("Ask-name-SUB")

# global variables
var_name = StringVar()
var_address = StringVar()

b = Button(root, text="Enter your name", command=lambda: get_value("Your name:", var_name))
b.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Enter your address", command=lambda: get_value("Your address:", var_address))
b.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Cancel", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()

# --- after --

name = var_name.get()
print "Print name, its length, its type"
print name, len(name), type(name)

address = var_address.get()
print "Print address, its length, its type"
print address, len(address), type(address)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Furas, it took me a while to understand it thoroughly but now I think I do!