# how to get the the value from the entry widget in tkinter in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get the data from the entry box.I'm not getting the use of those variables. It's showing me blank when I try to print the result. I tried using lambda but still not working. I'm new at this. Please show me where I'm wrong. I tried online but they are older version solutions.

```
def insertdata(E1):
       print(E1)


e1 = StringVar()

L1 = Label(F1, text ="Serial No:",anchor = E)
L1.grid(row = 0 ,column = 0)

E1  = Entry(F1,textvariable = e1)
E1.grid(row = 0 ,column = 2, sticky = N)
v1 = e1.get()
Button (F2,text = "Paid",command=lambda:insertdata(v1)).pack(side= TOP)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

Comment: You didn't give the user a chance to input anything, so of course it's empty.

Comment: do `e1.get()` to print it.

Comment: but I'm using variable v1 to get the value from e1. Is it wrong?

Comment: yeah! I got the answer instead of using `e1.get()`  I should use `E1.get()`. but it was just trial and error for me I don't know the exact reason behind it. can anyone tell me why?

Comment: @geekarshad `e1` is a string variable bound to `E1`, so `e1.get()` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how to get content in `entry` widget and print. With the code you posted, you are doing a lot of wrong things; you cannot use `pack` and `grid` to postion your widget in the same window. Also never do this: `Button (F2,text = "Paid",command=lambda:insertdata(v1)).pack(side= TOP)`,  but always position your layout manager on the next line.

**EXAMPLE**

`b = Button (F2,text = "Paid",command=lambda:insertdata(v1))`
`b.pack(side= TOP)`

**FULL CODE**

```
from tkinter import *


def insertdata():
    print(e1)
    print(E1.get())


root = Tk()    

L1 = Label( text="Serial No:", anchor=E)
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)

e1 = StringVar()
E1 = Entry( textvariable=e1)
E1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)

b = Button( text="Paid", command=insertdata)
b.grid(row=10, column=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `v1` to `e1.get()` before anything could be entered into the entry.

I tried the following code, and it works fine.

```
from tkinter import * # SHOULD NOT USE.
F1=Tk()
F2=Tk()
def insertdata(E1):
    print(E1)


e1 = StringVar()

L1 = Label(F1, text ="Serial No:",anchor = E)
L1.grid(row = 0 ,column = 0)

E1  = Entry(F1,textvariable = e1)
E1.grid(row = 0 ,column = 2, sticky = N)

Button (F2,text = "Paid",command=lambda:insertdata(e1.get())).pack(side= TOP) # SHOULD NOT USE.
```

Comment: Nope. It's still showing the blank space. I'm not able to understand the use of `E1` and `e1` in my code. `E1.get()` is working fine for me `Button (F2,text = "Paid",command= lambda:insertdata(E1.get())).pack(side= TOP)` like this.

Comment: @geekarshad Really? I was able to get an output just fine when I tried that solution. I'll edit to include the full code.