# Can't print out entry in tkinter python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I enter a value into the entry it then should print to the console, however, instead it prints a new line and nothing else. I'm new to tkinter and am just testing things out at the moment.

```
def main(self, event= None):
    v = StringVar()
    entry1 = Entry(width = 20, textvariable = v)
    entry1.bind("<Return>", self.main)
    entry1.focus()
    self.removeWidgits()
    homeLabel.place_forget()
    exitButton.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    entry1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    v = entry1.get()
    print(v)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

Comment: You're calling `entry1.get()` about a millisecond after you create the widget. You would have to be able to type _really_ fast to enter something before the print statement.

Comment: I can see a couple problems here. It appears you are using a class method. That said you are trying to create an Entry field without passing its parent container. Instead you should create the entry field outside of the method in the `__init__` method most likely and then just get the entry info with a print statement.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to test your code. What you have provided does not make much sense without some more context. I would never build a method that looks like this because it not very efficient and relatively redundant.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you want to print text in the entry when `Return` is pressed. Here is a copy of your code that prints the text on pressing enter.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(width = 20, textvariable = v)
entry1.bind("<Return>", lambda _:print(entry1.get()))
entry1.focus()
entry1.place(x = 0, y = 0)

root.mainloop()
```