# I found a function a bit of code on here that works but I don't understand why it works

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The code is below from this post:

[Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

The argument in the return_entry is 'en' and when I deleted it out it says a positional argument is missing. What is the `def return_entry('en')` mean and why does it only work with it.

Why cant i just use:

```
def return_entry():
```

The en argument makes no sense to me...

```
from tkinter import *    
master = Tk()

def return_entry(en):
    content = entry.get()
    print(content)



Label(master, text="Input: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

entry = Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Connect the entry with the return button
entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry) 

mainloop()
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: return_entry() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Only throws an error when I remove en and hit enter after I enter input in the entry box.

Comment: All Tkinter event bindings receive a single parameter when they are invoked, which contains details about the event.  It's not particularly useful in your case, since you are binding to such a specific event, but imagine if you had bound to an arbitrary keypress - without that parameter, you'd have no way to tell what key had been pressed.

Answer (score 3):

`bind` expects function which can get argument to send `event` to this function - and it will run it as `return_entry(event)`. And this is why you can't use function without argument.

You can even use this `event` to get access to `entry` - so you can assing the same function to different entries and ifunction will get text from correct entry

```
def return_entry(event):
    content = event.widget.get()
    print(content)
```

---

Sometimes we may want to use the same function with `command=` which doesn't send `event` to function and then we can use `event=None` but then we can't use `event` inside function

```
def return_entry(event=None):
    content = entry.get()
    print(content)

entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)

tk.Button(..., command=return_entry)
```

---

Working examples:

Function binded to two entries:

```
import tkinter as tk

def return_entry(event):
    content = event.widget.get()
    print(content)

root = tk.Tk()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()

entry1.bind('<Return>', return_entry)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

entry2.bind('<Return>', return_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

Function assigned to `Entry` and `Button`

```
import tkinter as tk

def return_entry(event=None):
    content = entry.get()
    print(content)

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=return_entry)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```