# Tkinter Entry's get function returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to use an Entry widget to get the user's data and then print it.
[Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)
This didn't help me.

This is my code

```
message = ''
    # start_chatting function
    def start_chatting ():
        global message
        master2 = tk.Tk()
        master2.geometry("1280x720")
        master2.title("Messenger")
        label = tk.Label(master2, text = "Messenger!!!",bg = '#1e00ff',fg ='yellow',width = 35, height = 5).place(x = 500, y = 0)
        username_label = tk.Label(master2,text = usernames[position_counter],bg = '#91806d',fg ='white',width = 10, height = 2).place(x = 0, y = 100)
        v = StringVar()
        L1 = Label(master2, text = "Type your message : ").place(x=0, y = 680)
        e = Entry(master2,textvariable = v)
        e.insert(END, '')
        e.pack()
        e.place(x = 115, y = 680)
        submit_button = Button(master2,text = "Submit",command = submit_f).place(x = 200, y = 680)
        message = message+ v.get()
        master2.mainloop()

#submit_f function  
def submit_f ():
    global message
    print(message)
```

Keep in mind that this is a part of my code and not all of it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `e.get()` is one thing, `v.get()` is apparently a different beast. In your code you're calling `StringVar`'s `get` method, not `Entry`'s

Comment: I tried e.get() but i got the same result.

Comment: Well, if the only code that attempts to retrieve the value is `message = message+ v.get()`, then this will be executed even before the GUI appears, so you won't even have a chance to input anything. Your `submit_f` should be `get`ting data from the `Entry` each time you press the button

Comment: The indentation in the code looks broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function prints nothing beacause you have changed the `message` value in the current function where the entry box is defined.

So, when you write `v.get()`, it generally returns an empty text.The `message` variable needs to call every time when `submit` button is pressed. Hence, `message` variable should be changed inside `submit_f()` function.

Here's the Solution,

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

message = ''
    # start_chatting function
def start_chatting ():
    global v
    master2 = Tk()
    master2.geometry("1280x720")
    master2.title("Messenger")
    label = Label(master2, text = "Messenger!!!",bg = '#1e00ff',fg ='yellow',width = 35, height = 5).place(x = 500, y = 0)
    username_label = Label(master2,text = usernames[position_counter],bg = '#91806d',fg ='white',width = 10, height = 2).place(x = 0, y = 100)
    L1 = Label(master2, text = "Type your message : ").place(x=0, y = 680)
    v = StringVar()
    e = Entry(master2,textvariable = v)
    e.insert(END, '')
    e.pack()
    e.place(x = 115, y = 680)
    submit_button = Button(master2,text = "Submit",command = submit_f).place(x = 200, y = 680)
    master2.mainloop()

#submit_f function
def submit_f ():
    global message
    message = message + " " + v.get()
    print(message)

start_chatting()
```