# Tkinter: I can't use the 'get' function to get information from an entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I can't use the `.get()` function anymore for some reason.

Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def submit():
    file = open('database.txt', 'w')
    file.write('Username:', un, '\nPassword:', pw)
    file.close()

wn = Tk()
wn.geometry('500x200')

Label(text='Geben Sie hier Ihren Benutzername ein:').pack()
username = Entry().pack()

Label(text='\n').pack()

Label(text='Geben Sie hier Ihr Passwort ein:').pack()
password = Entry().pack()

Label(text='\n').pack()


un = str(username.get())
pw = str(password.get())

btn = Button(text='Submit', command=submit).pack()


wn.mainloop()
```

It used to work in the past, so I don't really know what to do.

The error I get looks like this:

> un = str(username.get())    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables username, password and btn in your code are not `Entry()`, `Entry()` and `Button()` objects as you might think, but the returns of `pack()` method (it seems it doesn't return anything, so all of these are NoneType objects).

If you intend to access these objects as `Entry()` or `Button()` objects further down in your code, you should separate initiation and `pack()` into two lines as:

```
username = Entry()
username.pack()

password = Entry()
password.pack()

btn = Button(text='Submit', command=submit)
btn.pack()
```