# Tkinter, use .get() for an entry widget initialized in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still trying to understand classes. I have used a class to easily initialize several identical labels and entry box widgets. Here is my code:

import tkinter as tk

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, master, row_number, text_entry):
        item = tk.Label(master, fg="white", bg="#300000",
                        text="Tile # " + text_entry + ":",
                        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))
        user_input = tk.Entry(master, width=50)
        item.grid(column=0, row=rows, padx=(0, 30), pady=(0, 10))
        user_input.grid(column=1, row=row_number, padx=(0, 30), pady=(0, 10))
        self.ent = user_input.get()
```

I was under the impression that I could use "self.ent = user_input.get()" to get the user input from the entry widget within my Tile object:

```
example = Tile(root,5,"5")

# then later have a button to call this action:

def button_clicked():
    print(example.ent)
```

This isn't working... How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You retrieved the value from the Entry *immediately* after creating it.  There WAS NO USER INPUT YET, how could there possibly have been anything typed in that millisecond or so?  You need to do the `.get()` later, in `button_clicked()` for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

Comment: You need to bind the entry widget to a string var and then call the `.get()` method on it as a stringVar updates every time there is a change, so there is no need for a button cclick or any other event to update it. check [this] (https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could make `ent` a property of the Tile class. This way the get method will be called each time you try to read `ent`

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, master, row_number, text_entry):
        item = tk.Label(master, fg="white", bg="#300000",
                        text="Tile # " + text_entry + ":",
                        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))
        user_input = tk.Entry(master, width=50)
        item.grid(column=0, row=rows, padx=(0, 30), pady=(0, 10))
        user_input.grid(column=1, row=row_number, padx=(0, 30), pady=(0, 10))

    @property
    def ent(self):
        return user_input.get()
```

Then you just do `print(example.ent)` as before and it will print the current value of the `user_input` field

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when I do this the property is unable to call user_input

Comment: @YangTegap Can you share the error message? You didn't share enough code for me to be able to execute the code so I had to guess and the code is untested