# I want to get the text from this variable using customtkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I want to get the text from this, How do I get it?
I've instaled tkniter, customtkinter but idk how to get the text from this

`entry1=customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=220, placeholder_text='Username')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Tkinter Entry's get function returning nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727131/why-is-tkinter-entrys-get-function-returning-nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/entry/) will take you to customtkinter documentation. Navigate to CTk Entry in CTk Widgets, one of the methods of CTkEntry is .get() which returns the string in the entry field.

This is the code to access the value of the entered fields Username and Password.

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title("app")
root.geometry("500x350")


def login():
   username = entry1.get()
   password = entry2.get()
   print(username)
   print(password)


frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)


label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Login System", 
font=("Roboto",24))
label.pack(pady=12,padx=10)


entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, 
placeholder_text="Username")
entry1.pack(pady=12,padx=10)


entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, 
placeholder_text="Password", show="*")
entry2.pack(pady=12,padx=10)


button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame,text="Login", 
command=login, fg_color = "blue")
button.pack(pady=12,padx=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/3d86b5a14f7f9d9298a763958962232f9e9df412/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py) for customtkinter, it seems like you can bind a `customtkinter.StringVar()` to the entry's `textvariable` and call `get()` on that variable

```
# instantiate a StringVar to store the entry contents
entry1_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value='Test')
# instantiate the entry widget
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(
    master=frame,
    width=220,
    placeholder_text='Username',
    # bind the variable to this widget
    textvariable=entry1_var,
)
entry1.pack()
print(entry1_var.get())
# => Test
```

However, you *should* also be able to call `get()` directly on the `CTkEntry` widget itself without having to worry about instantiating / binding to `textvariable`

```
entry1.get()
```

Comment: I'm using an if statement to check for Username and Password but, its not working with this code, Idk why

Comment: You'll have to include more of your code with your question - I'm afraid I can't help much without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: I tried but, I wasn't able to post it for some reason

Comment: Were you running into formatting problems? If you want to include a block of code in the body of your question, surround it with three backtick "`" characters \```<your code here>```