# I want to save an input from my GUI in a textfile, using TKinter. how can I save to text file from entries

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, text-files

```
def submit(self):
    if get1 =="":
        print('please input a name')
    else:
        with open('users.txt',"a") as f:
            f.write(get1)
        f.close()
```

users.txt is my file, and namee as you can see below is the Entry variable,
all with tkinter

```
self.namee = Entry(frame)
self.namee.grid(row=7,column=1)
```

this is the entry i have made

```
get1 = self.namee.get()
```

this is the getter i have made:

```
self.submit = Button(frame, text="Submit",command=self.submit)
self.submit.grid(row = 26, column=0, sticky=W)
```

and this is the button to run the function the start the if statement

Comment: You've told us what you want, but not what you need help with. There's no question in your question. Have you worked through a tkinter tutorial, and have you read the documentation for Entry and other widgets?

Comment: The answers to this question should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget

Comment: i have now edited the code again using the links provided and when i click the submit button apparently the entry is empty as nothing goes into my 'users.txt' file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the value of entry field inside your submit function. Try this

```
def submit(self):
    get1 = self.namee.get()
    if get1 =="":
        print('please input a name')
    else:
        with open('users.txt',"a") as f:
            f.write(get1)
        #f.close() # Not needed, with closes f for you.
```