# Tkinter Serial Input data

Tags: tkinter, serial-port, int, tkinter-entry

I made a function that checks if there's any activity on a serial port, taking its serial data from a tkinter Gui and then returns an answer, However i am having a problem in initializing the variables.

i tried setting it as int but i get this problem, if not i get another error telling me that the baud rate is not valid.

```py
#serial port checking function
def check_SERIAL(port_name='/dev/ttyUSB0',baud_rate=115200,serial_parity='serial.PARITY_NONE',stop_bits=8,byte_size=8,time_out=1): #pings serial interface, VAR: port name, baud rate, parity, stopB, byteS, Timeout
    logger.debug('checking Serial Connection')
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port=port_name,
        baudrate=baud_rate,
        parity=serial_parity,
        stopbits=stop_bits,
        bytesize=byte_size,
        timeout=time_out
        )
    time.sleep(1)
    A=0
    try:
        ser.write("||;1>get logfile\r\n".encode())
        for x in range(0,1000):
            if ser.inWaiting() > 10:
                A=1
    finally:
        ser.close()
        if A==0:
            raise device_crashed(" Device Crashed")
        time.sleep(1)
#entries from the GUI 
entry_PORT = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_PORT.grid(row=14,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
entry_BAUD = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_BAUD.grid(row=16,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
entry_PARITY = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_PARITY.grid(row=18,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
entry_STOPB = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_STOPB.grid(row=20,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
entry_BYTES = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_BYTES.grid(row=22,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
#running code:
def start_testing():
    try:
        logger.debug('test has started ')
        #checking device interfaces if are ok
        check_SERIAL(port_name=str(entry_PORT),baud_rate=int(entry_BAUD),serial_parity=entry_PARITY,stop_bits=entry_STOPB,byte_size=entry_BYTES)


    except Exception as e: #general exceptions
        logger.error('Something went wrong: ' + str(e))
button=Button(second_frame, text='Start Test',borderwidth=10,command= start_testing)
button.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.4,relwidth=0.15,relheight=0.12)
```

The error i get:

```
int() argument must be as 'string, a bytes like object or a number, not 'Entry'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get contents of a Tkinter Entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: Is that port name correct? `/dev/TTYUSB0` sure looks like it should be `/dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: it is not a duplicate i already checked those, and i corrected the port name, it was just a typo here.