# how do I create entry fields and buttons to get the content from the entry field using iteration in tkinter for python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, iteration, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to make a tkinter GUI with a certain amount of buttons and entry fields that is specified by the user, so in this code below for example if the user specifies the variable number to be 3 I want there to be 3 entry boxes and , and I want to set it up so that if I type a value into the first field and click the button next to it, I want that button to read the value from the entry field next to it. I also need to assign each entry field to a variable that will be created through the same iterative loop. However, I'm having difficulty especially in regards to mapping the buttons to the entry fields, as I always seem to run up against an error with the text "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'". Would anyone be able to either fix my code or help me find an alternative solution to the problem? Sorry if the description's a bit confusing.
This is different from just a problem of just getting the contents of the entry widget as I need it to create a certain amount of entry widgets and buttons using iteration, and the question that my question has been marked a duplicate of doesn't explain how to iteratively map each entry field to each button. For example, if I enter 3 as the variable, I need the program to create entry field 1, entry field 2 and entry field 3 and button 1, button 2 and button 3 and then map each button to its respective entry field using iteration.
I've tried using dictionaries, but this doesn't seem to help much.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
number = 3
d={}
def callBack():
    print(d["E{0}".format(i)].get())
    return
for i in range(0,number):
    d["E{0}".format(i)] = tk.Entry(root)
    d["E{0}".format(i)].grid(row=i, column=0)
    d["B{0}".format(i)] = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=callBack)
    d["B{0}".format(i)].grid(row=i, column=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get contents of a Tkinter Entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: You need to provide a callback as the `command` parameter. In the callback, call the relevant `get` method.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` - this is what you will receive if you define your widget and call the geometry manager method at the same time. Read [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: @DavidCullen I did what you said although I still have the same error!

Comment: @HenryYik I tried that and it helped somewhat, but I still have a error where no matter what button I click, only the data in the third entry box is printed. How can I fix that so button 1 prints entry box 1, button 2 prints entry box 2 and button 3 prints entry box 3?

Comment: Also I need to be able to create another iteration where a variable is created for each button so the data in entry 1 goes to Variable1 when button 1 is clicked, entry 2 goes to Variable2 when button 2 is clicked and entry 3 goes to Variable3 when button 3 is clicked

Comment: @ShtarkBochur When I tried running your code, I realized the real problem is that you were saving the result of the `grid` calls, which is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the `Entry` and `Button` before calling `grid`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

number = 3
root = tk.Tk()

def get_on_click(widget_dict, entry_name):
    def on_click():
        result = widget_dict[entry_name].get()
        print("%s = %s" % (entry_name, result))
        return result
    return on_click

d = dict()
for i in range(0, number):
    entry_name = "E{0}".format(i)
    button_name = "B{0}".format(i)
    print(entry_name, button_name)
    d[entry_name] = tk.Entry(root)
    d[entry_name].grid(row=i, column=0)
    d[button_name] = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=get_on_click(d, entry_name))
    d[button_name].grid(row=i, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This should help you get started.

In your comment, you ask how to save the value in the `Entry`. I would create a class to handle everything:

```py
import tkinter as tk

number = 3
root = tk.Tk()

class EntryButton(object):
    def __init__(self, root, number):
        self.number = number
        self.entry = tk.Entry(root)
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=self.on_click)
        self.entry.grid(row=number, column=0)
        self.button.grid(row=number, column=1)
        self.value = None

    def on_click(self):
        self.value = self.entry.get()

storage = dict()
for i in range(0, number):
    storage[i] = EntryButton(root, i)

root.mainloop()

for i in range(0, number):
    value = storage[i].value
    print(f"storage[{i}] = {value}")
```

As you can see, this eliminates a lot of extra work.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a massive help for me and easy to understand. Any idea how I would be able to assign the entry field data to a variable via iteration, for example if entry field 1 has the data "potatoes" in it, how would I then assign that data to a variable called variable1 made through iteration so that variable1 = "potatoes" and the same with entry field 2 and variable2 and so on?

Comment: I would create a class and use it to handle all the work. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" has been asked probably a hundred times on this site, and the answer is always the same.

In python, when you do `x = y().z()`, `x` will be given the value of `z()`. In the case of `x=tk.Entry(...).grid(...)`, `x` will be `None` because `grid(...)` always returns `None`. The solution is to *always* call `grid` or `pack` or `place` separate from when you create a widget.

You also claim you are having problems with dictionaries, but I don't see any problem in your code other than you are making it more difficult than necessary. You can directly use `i` as an index without having to build up a string for the index. If you need to keep track of both buttons and entries, I recommend two variables rather than one.

Part of the problem may also have to do with the fact you're trying to do something very odd in your `command`. You're trying to call the `get` method of the entry, but that's pointless since it simply returns a value that gets thrown away. In almost all cases, the correct solution is to write a proper function rather than trying to squeeze functionality into a lambda.

Example:

```
def handle_click(i):
    entry = entries[i]
    print("the value is {}".format(entry.get()))

buttons = {}
entries = {}
for i in range(0,number):
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="test", command=lambda i=i: handle_click(i))

    buttons[i] = button
    entries[i] = entry

    entry.grid(row=i, column=0)
    button.grid(row=i, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For get text from entry

```
Entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
# 1.0 for get first line.
# end-1c for if last letter space, this deletes it.
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget)