# Problem while dynamically creating Entry widgets in pop-up window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to make a pop-up window that gets the strings from Entry widgets, the number of widgets is determined by the user on a primary window. So if the user inputs 5 fields are required then the pop-up should have 5 Entry widgets to get 5 different strings, if the user inputs 4 the pop-up has 4 widgets and so forth. Using help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378323/how-do-i-create-entry-fields-and-buttons-to-get-the-content-from-the-entry-field?rq=1) I wrote the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")

class EntryButton(object):
    def __init__(self, rootWin, numberEn):
        self.number = numberEn
        self.entry = tk.Entry(rootWin)
        self.button = tk.Button(rootWin, text="test", command=self.on_click)
        self.entry.grid(row=numberEn, column=0)
        self.button.grid(row=numberEn, column=1)
        self.value = None

    def on_click(self):
        self.value = self.entry.get()

def popup_window(numberOfEntries, storageDict):
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.title("Pop-Up Window")

    dictionary = dict()
    for i in range(0, numberOfEntries):
        dictionary[i] = EntryButton(window, i)
    
    storageDict = dictionary

numberVar = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, text='Enter how many markers you are using:', font=('bold', 10)).grid(column= 0, row= 3)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=numberVar).grid(column= 1, row=3)
number = numberVar.get()

mainStorage = dict()
initialPlotBtn = tk.Button(root, text='Start Labelling')
initialPlotBtn.config(command =lambda:
    popup_window(numberOfEntries=number, storageDict=mainStorage)
)
initialPlotBtn.grid(column = 1, row = 4)

root.mainloop()

for key in mainStorage:
    print(key, mainStorage[key])
```

My main window works as seen here:
[MainWindowImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCg9u.png).
However once creating the pop-up window it shows empty like this:
[Pop-upWindowImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyE6L.png).

I'm merely beginning to use tkinter, so there might be something i'm not getting here.
Using Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used value of `number` as an argument to `popup_window()` but `number` is zero because it is assigned right after the entry is created.

You should use `numberVar.get()` as the argument instead:

```
initialPlotBtn.config(command =lambda:
    popup_window(numberOfEntries=numberVar.get(), storageDict=mainStorage)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's such a small oversight now that I see it