# The Output is None, None, None Python using sql lite

Tags: sqlite, tkinter, python-3.6

Hello Everyone i need help why my output result is none in the print('bla bla') line so from my output is None, None, None that actually insert from npm , nama , and jurusan but the output is none ,can anybody help me solve it thanks

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



def Daftar():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Welcome to TutorialsPoint")
    window.geometry('400x400')
    window.configure(background = "grey");

    Lnpm = Label(window, text="Please Input Your npm: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Lnama = Label(window,text="Please Input Your nama: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Ljurusan = Label(window,text="Please Input Your jurusan: ").grid(row=2, column=0)

    npm = Entry(window).grid(row = 0,column = 1)
    nama = Entry(window).grid(row = 1,column = 1)
    jurusan = Entry(window).grid(row = 2,column = 1)
 def Clicked():

     print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (npm, nama, jurusan))

     connect = sqlite3.connect('Presensi.db')
     cur = connect.cursor()
     connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user(npm,nama,jurusan) values(?,?,?)", (str(npm),str(nama),str(jurusan)))
     connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO presensi(nama) values(?)", (str(nama),))
     connect.commit()
     cur.close()

    btn = ttk.Button(window ,text="Register",command= Clicked()).grid(row=3,column=0)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this help? [tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: No Sorry, if i using that from the help u given, only pass without showing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two big issues here:

- the [`grid()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) function of the `Entry` object returns `None` and that's what `npm`, `nama` and `jurusan` are `None`. What you have to do is store the `Entry` object, not the value returned from `grid()`.
- you're not calling [`get()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget) on the `Entry` objects to get their input values

What you can do is create a class in which you store the `Entry` objects. The callback function of the `Button` object can then be a method of the class.

I've reorganised your code to do this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
import sqlite3

class Daftar:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.window = master
        self.window.title("Welcome to TutorialsPoint")
        self.window.geometry('400x400')
        self.window.configure(background = "grey");

        self.Lnpm = Label(self.window, text="Please Input Your npm: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.Lnama = Label(self.window,text="Please Input Your nama: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.Ljurusan = Label(self.window,text="Please Input Your jurusan: ").grid(row=2, column=0)

        #Entry objects for later use
        self.npm = Entry(self.window)
        self.npm.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
        self.nama = Entry(self.window)
        self.nama.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
        self.jurusan = Entry(self.window)
        self.jurusan.grid(row = 2,column = 1)

        self.btn = Button(self.window ,text="Register",command = self.Clicked).grid(row=3,column=0)


    def Clicked(self):
        #Get the entry values
        npm = self.npm.get()
        nama = self.nama.get()
        jurusan = self.jurusan.get()
        print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (npm, nama, jurusan))

        connect = sqlite3.connect('Presensi.db')
        cur = connect.cursor()
        connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user(npm,nama,jurusan) values(?,?,?)", (npm,nama,jurusan))
        connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO presensi(nama) values(?)", (nama,))
        connect.commit()
        cur.close()


root = Tk()
my_gui = Daftar(root)
root.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This Really Helping Thanks