# Tkinter packing empty widgets if "if statement" is False

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, widget

I am creating a search function in my tkinter program and I have a problem with empty widgets getting packed if the ifstatement where the widgets should get packed in is false.

I try to explain what I am trying to do:
I have a while loop which is looping through all files in a folder.
In the while loop is a if statement which checks if the filename contains the searched letters.
If yes, a Label with the filename will be packed. If no, nothing should happen.
But when the filename doesn´t contain the searched letters, a empty widget is been packed.

Here is a short example of my code:

```
whileLoop = True
search = Entry(root)
fileNameList = ["abc","def","ghi"]
whileLoopCounter = 0

while whileLoop == True:
   if search in fileNameList[whileLoopCounter]:
      Label(root, text=fileNameList[whileLoopCounter])
      whileLoop = False
   whileLoopCounter += 1
```

This is a very short version of my code, because the real code would be way to long. But I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this operation is much more suited for a ```for``` loop since you really only want to iterate through fileNameList

Comment: @YulkyTulky It may look like in this example, but I just wrote the important things in the example and in my code there are some more things that would not work in a for loop.

Comment: what is the return of "Entry"?

Comment: @user1438644 the letters you are searching

Comment: @nexCs look at the code below

Comment: @user1438644 That is basicly what I am doing... I think this wont change anything

Comment: @nexCs please show Entry code it will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214010/discussion-between-nexcs-and-user1438644).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
search = Entry(root)
fileNameList = ["abc","def","ghi"]
for d in fileNameList:
    if d in search.get():
        Label(root, text=d)
```

try this! it uses "any". Also you need to do "in" on 'each' string not
on the whole list!