# If-Else not working in Tkinter under functions please solve this question :

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg

root = Tk()


def myaccount():
    Label(root, text="\n\nEnter Your Account Number : ").pack(anchor="nw")
    global en
    en = Entry(font=" helectiva 11")
    en.pack(anchor="nw")

    def detail():
        if en=="91xxxxxxxx":
                Label(text="Hello").pack()
    b = Button(root, text="View my Account Details",borderwidth=10,command=detail)
    b.pack(anchor="nw")

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("——Welcome To Banking System Application——")
txt1 = StringVar()
txt1.set("*****************************************************")
txt2 = StringVar()
txt2.set("\n\nChoose from the Options :")
txt3 = StringVar()
txt3.set("—————————————————————————————")


Label(root, textvariable = txt).pack()
Label(root, textvariable = txt1).pack()
Label(root, textvariable = txt2).pack()
Label(root, textvariable= txt3).pack()
Button(root, text="View My Account",borderwidth=10,command=myaccount).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=32)
Button(root, text="New Account",borderwidth=10).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=72)
Button(root, text="Make a Transactiom",borderwidth=10).pack(anchor="nw")
Button(root, text="Exit",borderwidth=10,command=quit).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=170)

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me with this. The `if` clause in my `detail` function is not working. I tried to solve it for 5 hours straight but couldn't find the correct reason. But if you find the reason please give the answer, I will be very thankful to that person.

Comment: If `en` is an `Entry` object, how could it be equal to a string? It seems that you need to get its contents and compare that to a string - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget) is a post on how to get the contents of an `Entry`.

Comment: I couldn't understand . Could you please explain again @Random Davis ?

Comment: in short use `if en.get() == '91xxxxxxxx':` and read the documentation next time before asking and do a little debugging yourself like `print(en)` for example

Comment: TL;DR: `if en.get() == "91xxxxxxxx":`

Comment:  I thought I will have follow option also . I am new to overstackflow . And also struggled to post this question

Comment: Thank you @krmogi if you answered But I can't see your answer

Comment: Yeah I got the answer Thank you@krmogu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entry object cannot be a string. Instead, you must get the text *inside* the entry object:

```
if en.get() == '91xxxxxxxx'
    Label(text="Hello").pack()
```

Final code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg

root = Tk()


def myaccount():
    Label(root, text="\n\nEnter Your Account Number : ").pack(anchor="nw")
    global en
    en = Entry(font=" helectiva 11")
    en.pack(anchor="nw")

    def detail():
        if en.get() == '91xxxxxxxx'
            Label(text="Hello").pack()
    b = Button(root, text="View my Account Details",borderwidth=10,command=detail)
    b.pack(anchor="nw")

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("——Welcome To Banking System Application——")
txt1 = StringVar()
txt1.set("*****************************************************")
txt2 = StringVar()
txt2.set("\n\nChoose from the Options :")
txt3 = StringVar()
txt3.set("—————————————————————————————")


Label(root, textvariable = txt).pack()
Label(root, textvariable = txt1).pack()
Label(root, textvariable = txt2).pack()
Label(root, textvariable= txt3).pack()
Button(root, text="View My Account",borderwidth=10,command=myaccount).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=32)
Button(root, text="New Account",borderwidth=10).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=72)
Button(root, text="Make a Transactiom",borderwidth=10).pack(anchor="nw")
Button(root, text="Exit",borderwidth=10,command=quit).pack(anchor="nw",ipadx=170)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you @krmogi